# Memory Locations of Vectors not Continuous

Tags: c++, vector, memory-management, stl, c++17

I am using C++ on Kubuntu 20.04 and ran the following piece of code:

```
   vector<int> v(10,2);
   cout<<sizeof(int)<<"\n";
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
      cout<<&(v[i])<<"\n";
```

The output was:

```
4
0x55967f666f10
0x55967f666f14
0x55967f666f18
0x55967f666f1c
0x55967f666f20
0x55967f666f24
0x55967f666f28
0x55967f666f2c
0x55967f666f30
0x55967f666f34
```

If vectors store data sequentially in memory (as chunk size 4 bytes above), Then why after "**0x55967f666f18**" is "**0x55967f666f1c**" rather than "**0x55967f666f22**"?

Comment: Do you know how hexadecimal numbers work? What comes after 9, for example?

Comment: Because `0x55967f666f18` < `0x55967f666f1c` < `0x55967f666f22`? More simply (ignoring the leading digits) `0x1c` < `0x22` -- even if you don't know hexadecimal, doesn't this seem to follow from `1 < 2`? (BTW, if you don't know hexadecimal, it might have been better to ask why `c` appears as a digit since that seems more basic than putting the numbers in order.)

Comment: `(0x55967f666f1c - 0x55967f666f18) == 4 == sizeof(int) (on your machine)`

Comment: ohkay...I got it... I'm not very familiar with hexadecimals... Well thanks for answering @cegien

Answer (score 4):

You're thinking in the decimal (Base 10) number system, but the pointers are printed in hexadecimal system (Base 16). Hexadecimal is a pretty important system in computing.

In hexadecimal you have the digits:

0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, A, B, C, D, E, F

the addresses are correct and contiguous. If you want to check them out in Base 10 use a converter like: https://www.binaryhexconverter.com/hex-to-decimal-converter

The two addresses in decimal are:

94104870874904
94104870874908